# Packing integers and floats to bytearray for sending over socket

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sockets, floating-point

I want to transmit bytearray from Python using Socket to my C application. So my bytearray should consist of 1000 elements which will be packed like this: integer, float, integer, float... etc.

So currently what I'm doing is:

```
bytes = bytearray()
for k in range(0, 500):
   bytes += struct.pack("i", integer_number)
   bytes += struct.pack("f", float_number)
```

But I think that takes to much time, because every time when "+=" is executed, new array is created, values are copied to new bytearray and then new value is added. Am I right?

So is there faster approach to do this? For example my values that need to be converted to bytearray are stored in the list, so can i create bytearray from those values somehow faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `struct.pack_into` to put data in a preallocated buffer:

```
import struct

number_of_pairs = 500
ints = range(number_of_pairs)
floats = map(float, ints)

fmt = '!if'

st = struct.Struct(fmt)

binary = bytearray(number_of_pairs * st.size)

for offset, i, f in zip(range(0, len(binary), st.size), ints, floats):
  st.pack_into(fmt, binary, offset, i, f)

for pair in struct.iter_unpack(fmt, binary):
  print(pair)
```

This version runs 1.96 times faster on my machine.